# C# Dealing with Large Strings and memory efficiency

Tags: c#, string, split, substring

I was wondering... If I want to store a MASSIVE string in my program and also store sub strings of the main string (i.e. store every word and store every sentence as arrays of strings) how can I do so without making 2 copies of the first massive string?

In C++ I would just use pointers to parts of the string... Is there an equivalent method in C#?

Comment: Pointers in C++ are just memory addresses. Likewise you can store indices of the massive string which are integers (and take up the same memory than C++ pointers).

Comment: Why not store the indices of the start and end of the substring?

Comment: MASSIVE == maybe a full book..
See Tigran's answer, I just had a block and made this question as I was on my way to work so I would loose my train of thought.

Brain just skipped a beat, I left my seat and hit myself in the head... Hopefully this might be able to help somebody else

Comment: If you could store the index of sub-strings in an array in the way you want?

Comment: Yeah that's what I plan to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store *indices* of the *start* and *end* of that substring your going to refer to.

In this case, if your `string` is going to change over runtime of your program, your "substring" will refer to the most updated version of the `string`, but I'm not sure, cause it's not clear from the question, if this is actually an expected behavior.

Comment: I feel rather stupid.. I've staired at  the problem for a while.. And couldn't think of a solution...

Then as soon as I wrote the question and left my room, I was like...

Get String..
Convert to String[] for every word
Make {int start, int end} array for every sentence.

:| lol you don't think until you leave the computer... I would have thought a lil longer, but it was killing me and I was on my way to work so I was about to loose my train of thought.

Comment: @MichaelCrook: it happens, sometimes  :)